# Gradle Android: Choose SignConfig according to BuildType

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors

I want to add an `if` or something similar to my gradle build script, that decides wether to sign my App with the Debug-Key or Release Key accodring to what buildType I'm using. 
 I can't do that in the buildTypes section, because if have different release keys for my product flavours. I tried it with something like buildType.name, but gradle does not know this property.

```
   buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard.txt'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard.txt'
        }
    }

    signingConfigs {
        app1 {
            ....
        }


        app2 {
            ....
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        app1 {
            applicationId "com.test.app1"
        }
        app2 {
            applicationId "com.test.app2"
            if (buildType.name == 'release'){
                signingConfig signingConfigs.app2
            }

        }
    }
```

Edit: Ok I managed to solve it via gradle.properties: I add a property and set it true or false in buildtypes, and an if in the productFlavour add the signConfig if true.

Comment: I could use a more detailed answer..